# how do i solve apple mach-o linker error? Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time i insert these two lines of code i get this error message and i dont understand why at all.

```
   NSTimer *BirdMovement;
NSTimer *TunnelMovement;
```

Here is the whole Script

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int BirdFlight;
int RandomTopTunnelPosition;
int RandomBottomTunnelPosition;
int ScoreNumber;
NSInteger HighScoreNumber;

@interface Game : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *Bird;
    IBOutlet UIButton *StartGame;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *TunnelUp;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *TunnelDown;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Top;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Bottom;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Exit;
    IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;


    NSTimer *BirdMovement;
    NSTimer *TunnelMovement;

}

-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender;
-(void)BirdMoving;
-(void)TunnelMoving;
-(void)PlaceTunnels;
-(void)Score;
-(void)GameOver;

@end
```

I dont think the other Scripts are the issue, if anyone has an idea id be thankful.

Comment: attach your error report please

Comment: Is this what you needed?:  

duplicate symbol _HighScoreNumber in:
    /Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/City_Bird-dmbobiidtqifgqhhfmcholwebsgl/Build/Intermediates/City Bird.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/City Bird.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ViewController.o
    /Users/Kevin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/City_Bird-dmbobiidtqifgqhhfmcholwebsgl/Build/Intermediates/City Bird.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/City Bird.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Game.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 use -v to see invocation

Comment: check once **_HighScoreNumber** in more than one view controller using copy paste mode , just replace this method is working fine.